# Java ConcurrentHashMap implementation

Tags: java

I was just looking at the source code of Java's ConcurrentHashMap and found this line of code:

```
/*
 * The maximum number of times to tryLock in a prescan before possibly blocking on acquire in   
 * preparation for a locked segment operation. On multiprocessors, using a bounded number of  
 * retries maintains cache acquired while locating nodes.
 */
static final int MAX_SCAN_RETRIES =
              Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() > 1 ? 64 : 1
```

The `MAX_SCAN_RETRIES` is used in looking up entries while acquiring lock. My question is how is the number `64` determined for a multi-processor machine? Anybody know the theory behind the number `64`?

Comment: For reference, the source can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.Segment.0MAX_SCAN_RETRIES). The javadoc there is: "The maximum number of times to tryLock in a prescan before possibly blocking on acquire in preparation for a locked segment operation. On multiprocessors, using a bounded number of retries maintains cache acquired while locating nodes."

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood why you were commenting it.  Deleting that comment.

Comment: @Vulcan No worries - I consolidated the comment to make more sense.

Comment: Good point. I will edit my question to include the comment.

Comment: Is Doug Lea on SO? He seems to have authored that class :)

Comment: As an aside, isn't using `Unsafe` in a serializable class a big no-no?

Comment: This question brilliantly demonstrates the value of good commenting. (Or in this case, the lack of it.)

Comment: I would expect 64 to have been experimentally determined.  (But @biziclop, Doug Lea pretty much wrote the book on these things, so I would feel fairly safe assuming he knew what he was doing.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sure, but he also wrote `AtomicReferenceArray`, which is a known gaping security hole. See here: http://www.metasploit.com/modules/exploit/multi/browser/java_atomicreferencearray (When it comes to security, trusting other people's experience isn't a great idea. Everyone makes mistakes.)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I guess " Each Java virtual machine thread has its own pc (program counter) register" tells something about why 64 bit chosen. I am still trying to figure out multi-processor and pc register relationship)http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Overview.doc.html.

Answer (score 9):

When dealing with lock retries across multiple CPUs there is a balance that you strike between attempting to get the lock quickly (spinning) and allowing the CPU to switch to another thread to avoid wasting CPU time spinning on the lock that isn't going to be released soon.  The actual number of spins allowed for a CPU to attempt to obtain a lock is strongly affected by both the actual speed of the overall system as well as by the amount of code that typically executes within the critical section.

This issue has deep roots in the Stopping Problem and many other issues related to OS design on SMP systems with respect to optimizing concurrency.  This kind of design choice is typically resolved via a trial and error approach across many applications; however the choice of 64 looks to me like an arbitrary call on the part of the implementer (the number is a power of two).

Unfortunately this particular code is both buggy and limiting.  Buggy in that the documentation for availableProcessors states "This value may change during a particular invocation of the virtual machine," hence potentially causing the lock to spin too many times (should the count move from > 1 to = 1) or too few (in the visa-versa case).  It is limiting in that a developer that really needs to tune concurrency in their application has no ability to do so as MAX_SCAN_RETRIES is final (though some tricks may be played with reflection).

Comment: your criticisms seem to be a bit reaching.  i can't think of many (any? system w/ hot-pluggable cpus?) situations where availableProcessors would change meaningfully while the jvm is running.  also, i highly doubt that tuning that specific parameter is going to make much of a difference in 99% of programs out there (such that providing the ability to tweak it would be worth the added code maintenance).

Comment: @biziclop - yeah, that occurred to me as well (i'm not an expert on all the functionality available in a vmware vm these days).  still not sure how often people would be swapping cpus in and out of a vmware (or similar) vm.  Seems i'm not far off on my assumption that it's use is probably scarce, based on [these results](http://www.boche.net/blog/index.php/2009/05/10/vsphere-memory-hot-add-cpu-hot-plug/) (notice that unplug doesn't work for any).

Comment: @jtahlborn They may not be doing it now, but remember, this is a standard class of the Java distribution. Having said that, the wording of the answer does make it sound a bit harsh.

Comment: @jtahlborn - I disagree, it is common on many enterprise architectures for a CPU to be hot-swapped (check out IBM servers).  This is NOT a rare occurrence on such systems.  In any case the fact is that this is the kind of parameter that should have a reasonable default and should be adjustable when necessary.

Comment: right, but the only situation we care about is 1 to >1 (not 2 to 3, or 3 to 4, etc...).  regardless, my point was just that your statement that the code is "buggy and limiting" is misleading at best.  i would imagine that just about no one would _actually_ care about this value in an actual running system (which is how it is coded, a sensible default for 99% of the world which also probably works just fine for the other 1%).

Comment: and, it _does_ have a reasonable default. also, it _is_ adjustable--you can compile your own constant (or more complex choice) into an OpenJDK jvm.